# phpunit, use other fixture in yii1

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, fixtures

I found example how use fixtures in manual

```
class CommentTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public $fixtures=array(
        'posts'=>'Post',
        'comments'=>'Comment',
    );

    …
}
```

or i can use like this 'post' => ':post'.
But i want use other fixtures in other tests, example: when i tested model Post i use "post.php" fixture, and when i tested model Author i want use post_for_author.php (data must insert in table post)

I try write like this:

```
class CommentTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public $fixtures=array(
        'posts_for_author'=>'Post',
        'comments'=>'Comment',
    );

    …
}
```

and other way 'posts_for_author'=>':post',
but it doesn't work. Please help me, how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isolated fixtures like this.

application/tests/unit:

```
    class CommentTest extends IsolatedFixtureDbTestCase {
        public $fixtures=array(
            'posts_for_author'=>'Post',
            'comments'=>'Comment',
        );
        ...
    }
```

and

application/tests:

```
abstract class IsolatedFixtureDbTestCase extends CDbTestCase
{
    private $basePathOld = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $fixturePath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.tests.fixtures.' . get_class($this));
        if (is_dir($fixturePath)) {
            $this->basePathOld = $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath;
            $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath = $fixturePath;
        }
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        if (null !== $this->basePathOld) {
            $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath = $this->basePathOld;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in application/tests/fixtures you can create folder CommentTest and there your fixtures for this class